# Flutter Textfield in DropDownMenue

Tags: flutter

I am trying to get a textfield to be an available option if the values in the drop down are not what the user wishes to choose.

I also intend to save this data to the sqflite database.

I also already have a working textfield that the user can input what he desired and it will be saved to a db. Just want to add a drop down menu for frequent inputs.

Comment: Also post what have you tried and what does it didn't work , otherwise it will be demo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your goal in Flutter, you can use a combination of a `DropdownButton` and a `TextField`. You can display the `TextField` when the user selects an option like "Other" from the `DropdownButton`.

Here's a step-by-step guide on how to do this:

1. Import the necessary Flutter packages:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

2. Create a `StatefulWidget` to manage the state of your form:

```dart
class MyForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyFormState createState() => _MyFormState();
}
```

3. In the `_MyFormState` class, define the variables and controllers you'll need:

```dart
class _MyFormState extends State<MyForm> {
  String selectedValue = "";
  String otherText = "";

  
  TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();

 
  List<String> dropdownItems = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Other"];
}
```

4. Build your widget tree within the `build` method of `_MyFormState`:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
    
      DropdownButton<String>(
        value: selectedValue,
        items: dropdownItems.map((String item) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: item,
            child: Text(item),
          );
        }).toList(),
        onChanged: (String newValue) {
          setState(() {
            selectedValue = newValue;

            // If "Other" is selected, show the TextField.
            if (newValue == "Other") {
              otherText = "";
            }
          });
        },
      ),

      // Show the TextField if "Other" is selected.
      if (selectedValue == "Other")
        TextField(
          controller: textEditingController,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              otherText = value;
            });
          },
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Enter your custom value"),
        ),

      //save the selected value or the custom value.
      ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          String finalValue = selectedValue == "Other" ? otherText : selectedValue;
          // Add your code to save finalValue to the database.
        },
        child: Text("Save"),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

5. Wrap your `MyForm` widget with a `Scaffold` and display it in your main app:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Dropdown and TextField Example")),
      body: MyForm(),
    ),
  ));
}
```

try this

Comment: Can you also  `post` the output/screenshot of the screen?? and how it is storing record in database?